# R interactive graphs for data manipulation

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, interactive, shiny

I need your advice about a project I'm gonna start on data manipulation. We own some meteorological stations acquiring data every 10 minutes. Now, we use an old data validation software that I want to update.

Recently I managed to build a web app with shiny and ggplot2 packages so we can plot or download (whole or subseted) our previously validated data sets. Now I would like to build a new app so we can plot non validated data and interactively perform validation.

Let's say we have temperature data showing usual values for a single day but with a completely wrong value (120 degrees). Is it possible to just click on that point and remove from the data set?

Googleing I read about iplots and rggobi packages but I am not sure if they fit my wishes. Please, could you point me to some packages, readings or examples so I can start my project?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try R's googlevis package

Comment: @user2510479 It seems to produce nice interactive plots but don't know if it can interact with data base to mark data as not valid. Needs further research. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend d3 (a javascript library) for building dynamic plots.  [Here](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/circle.html) is an example for destroying symbols.  You would just need to add an onclick action to make it interactive.

[**rCharts**](http://ramnathv.github.io/rCharts/) can be used to interface between R and javascript.  [Here](http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_512paths/) is an example with d3.

The nice thing about **rCharts** is that it can interface with many javascript libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will give it a try but I don't just want to destroy symbols in a chart but mark data as not valid in the data base. I don't know much about javascript, maybe a problem.